# How can I determine the average number of transactions per second in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'd like to see how many transactions per second an instance of MySQL server is processing, on average (per hour and per day). Is there some query to determine this? I've looked through performance_schema as well as information_schema, but nothing seems obvious.

*I am running version 5.6.14 for x86_64 on debian6.0*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at stats from `\s`? I wasn't sure by 'transaction' you simply mean queries.

Comment: Yes, sorry; queries. What do you mean by `\s`?

Comment: on mysql client type `\s` or `status;` and press enter. It gives you some useful info on server since start.

Comment: Ah, that worked. I was hoping for a way to break down queries by time period somehow. This may have to do; thanks.